# Displaying each image from a directory in an Image Control

Tags: c#, wpf, image, wpf-controls

I'd like to display the contents(.jpg files) from a local directory in an Image control. The images has to be replaced with a 5 sec delay.

```
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\somedir");
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                imgBox.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(item.FullName);
            }
```

Comment: And what do you need help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load images into a memory, then user a background thread to rotate them with the defined delay. Dispatcher call is required to access the UI control from a background thread.

```
List<Image> images;

void GetImagesIntoAList()
{
    List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\somedir");
                FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

                foreach (var item in files)
                {                        
                   FileStream stream = new FileStream(item.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                   Image i = new Image();
                   BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
                   src.BeginInit();
                   src.StreamSource = stream;
                   src.EndInit();
                   i.Source = src;
                   images.Add(i);
                }

   Thread rotator = new Thread(rotate);
   rotator.Start();
}

void rotate()
{
   foreach(var img in images)
   {
      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => 
      { 
         nameOfImageControlOnAWindow.Source = img;

      }
      );

      Thread.Sleep(5000);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes instead we can use `DispatcherTimer`. Also why make it load in the stream? Cant a `Binding` to `Source` property with with `IsAsync` as true work?

Comment: @AngleWPF, I would personally prefer to load all the images in the collection, so I know for sure how many images I have. Maybe I would need that number to show a progress of rotation, like Picture 1 of 6, etc.